# Unable to open face recoginition using biometric manager

Tags: android, androidx

```
    biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(this, executor,
            object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int,
                                                   errString: CharSequence) {
                    super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                                    "Authentication error: $errString", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                }

                override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(
                        result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                    super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                                    "Authentication succeeded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                }

                override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                    super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Authentication failed",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                }
            })

    promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("Biometric login for my app")
            .setSubtitle("Log in using your biometric credential")
            .setNegativeButtonText("Use account password")
            .build()

    val biometricLoginButton =
            findViewById<Button>(R.id.biometric_login)
    biometricLoginButton.setOnClickListener {
        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
    }
```

This will open fingerprint scanner everytime and if their is no finger print it show no fingerprint added error.

I want to open face recogination BioMetricPrompt. plz helpp

Comment: Note that even if a device has face recognition support, it may not be available for use through the BiometricPrompt API if it's not considered secure enough (as defined by [the Android CDD](https://source.android.com/compatibility/10/android-10-cdd). See in particular section 7.3.10).

Answer (score 0):

Biometric APIs can automatically handle Face recognition feature, if device supports it.

On which device, you are testing ?

The Biometric mode(Face, FingerPrint) configured by user in device settings, will be shown in Biometric Authetication UI, whene authenticate() of Biometric library is invoked. For user to configure Face biometric mode in device settings, device should support Face Authentication(hardware driven).Pixel 4 is one of the device supporting Face Authentication.When user configures Face authentication in settings, and if authenticate() is invoked, Face Authentication type of authentication UI will be shown. Face Authentication introduced in Android 10 is driven from Hardware.

Note : Earlier I thought, Soli chip is mandatory in device to support Android 10 Biometric APIS, but its wrong. I have edited the previous answer to correct my explanation. Any device compatible with Android Biometric specification would support it. https://source.android.com/security/biometric

Comment: I'm using One plus 6T

Comment: It wont work. Go through my explanation. Hope I answered your query.

Comment: Is their any way to check that my device has face recogination or not because I unlock my device using face unlock and samething I want to check inside my app.

Comment: As of Android 10, there is no API from Biometric Manager to find whether face recognition is supported in device. Face lock feature in your device might be provided by one plus. I dont think, you can find out in your App.

Comment: I don't see why Soli would be a requirement for face recognition to work through BiometricPrompt. Could you point to some documentation describing this? The Soli system might be used to speed up the face unlock procedure by allowing the device to guess when the user is about to attempt a face unlock. But there isn't really any need to guess when BiometricPrompt is going to be used, because that's something an app will request explicitly.

Comment: Hey Michael, Please refer this https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth. Here you can see that we can use face unlock in biometric prompt to unlock the app same as fingerprint.

Comment: @Michael : https://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/news/google-pixel-4-soli-radar-motion-sense-face-unlock-2077346
https://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/news/google-pixel-4-xl-price-in-india-launch-date-reason-not-in-india-2117507
https://www.biometricupdate.com/201910/google-pixel-4-not-for-sale-in-india-facial-recognition-works-with-closed-eyes

Comment: @AlokSingh I think you're replying to the wrong person.

Comment: @Basha Right. From the article: _"Soli will cue facial recognition sensors when a Pixel 4 is picked up to allow devices to automatically unlock for their owners. "Other phones require you to lift the device all the way up, pose in a certain way, wait for it to unlock, and then swipe to get to the home screen. Pixel 4 does all of that in a much more streamlined way"_. So like I said in my previous comment, it's used to speed up the face unlock procedure. But I still don't see what that has to do with using BiometricPrompt from an app.

Comment: @Michael : The Biometric mode(Face, FingerPrint) configured by user in device settings, will be shown in Biometric Authetication UI, whene authenticate() of Biometric library is invoked. For user to configure Face biometric mode in device settings, device should support Face Authentication(hardware driven).Pixel 4 is one of the device supporting Face Authentication.When user configures Face authentication in settings, and if authenticate() is invoked, Face Authentication type of authentication UI will be shown. Face Authentication introduced in Android 10 is driven from Hardware.

Comment: @Michael : Soli detects face for the aforementioned face unlock. It sees when we move the device in front of  face, then engages the proper sensors to scan face. Further info on it can be found in https://www.androidauthority.com/google-pixel-4-soli-motion-sense-1042448/. Note: I am not sure, if there is any device(without Soli) and it supports Android 10 Face detection . Let me know, if you have any info on it.

Comment: In all of those links I still only see information about how Soli is used to speed up the face unlock procedure. That's very different from being a required feature for face authentication to work / be allowed.

Comment: @Michael : You are right. Thanks for correcting my understanding.